# Add animation in toggleClass

Tags: jquery

I use this code to toggle a font awesome icon. The toggle is working but I want to give some animation there. But animation not working.

HTML:

```
<header>
    <h4><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></h4>
</header>
```

jQuery:

```
$('header h4').click(function() {
        $("i", this).toggleClass("fa-bars fa-times", 1000);
    });
```

Comment: what do you expect to happen? this doesn't make sense to animate turning a class on/off

Comment: I just want to make toggle the icon with animation. Toggle icon is working fine but can't put any animation there. Isn't it possible ?

Comment: but how do you want it to animate?

Comment: I tried but couldn't make it. I want toggle work duration will 0.5s something like this.

Comment: use `setInterval` if you want it to go back and forth.

Comment: I don't know how to use it with toggleclass :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want a fade in/out effect on your icons.

```js
$('header h4').click(function(e) {
    //if the icon has the class fa-bars
    if ($("i", this).hasClass('fa-bars')) {

      //fade the icon element out
      $("i", this).fadeOut('fast', function() {
        // remove the element from the dom
        $(this).remove();
      });

      // create the new element, append it to the dom, hide it immediately, then fade it in
      $('<i class="fa fa-times"></i>').appendTo($(this)).hide().fadeIn('fast');

    } else { //otherwise the icon has the other class (fa-times)
    
      //fade the icon element out
      $("i", this).fadeOut('fast', function() {
        // remove the element from the dom
        $(this).remove();
      });

       // create the new element, append it to the dom, hide it immediately, then fade it in
      $('<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>').appendTo($(this)).hide().fadeIn('fast');
    }
  });
```

```css
.fa-bars, .fa-times {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
 <h4><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></h4>
</header>
```